# Query Slowness Between Two Tables

Tags: mysql, performance, bigdata

If there is a result matching the value of **"parent_id"** in my **"table1"** and **"table2"** tables, I want to get the number of rows in the **"table1"** table.

**But the SQL query takes too long.**

There are **100 thousand** rows in table1.

There are **40 thousand** rows in table2.

A table data file for you to try
See:   https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/ddf8c467

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
parent_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
tes1 INT(1) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE table2 (id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
parent_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
tes2 INT(1) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

**SQL Query I use**

```
SELECT     COUNT(A.id) AS total
FROM       table1 A
LEFT JOIN  table2 B ON A.parent_id = B.parent_id
WHERE      B.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: create a index on **parent_id** on table B and use INNODB if possible

Comment: This is NOT sql server. tag removed

Comment: Hi @BerndBuffen ,

I applied the following SQL code on your recommendation and it worked.

Thank you so much.

Will there be a side effect of indexing?

`ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD INDEX (` parent_id`);`

Comment: with a index MySQL can find the over it. read this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-indexes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a index on parent_id on table B and use INNODB if possible.

you can also use **inner join**

```
SELECT     COUNT(A.id) AS total
FROM       table1 A
INNER JOIN  table2 B ON A.parent_id = B.parent_id;
```